# Integer value converting to floating point

Tags: c#, modbus

I have two ushort integer. Integers :-32768, 16992

Basically those two values are modbus holding registers integer value. I want to convert to float this integers. When higher/lower order value comes in negative my bit converter logic thorws below exception but Modbus poll shows that value as **35.12**

Error:- Value was either too large or too small for a UInt16.

```
void Main()
{
    GetSingle(16992,-32768);
}
public static float GetSingle(ushort highOrderValue, ushort lowOrderValue)
{
    return BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(lowOrderValue).Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(highOrderValue)).ToArray(), 0);
}
```

Comment: ushort states for "unsigned short", so it cannot be negative by definition.

Comment: But it also doesn't work for Long data type. if i use long instead of ushort. conrstion value shows NaN.

Comment: Well sure, because long is 8 bytes, two longs are 16 bytes but float is only 4 bytes. You need to clarify what you are trying to do, that is - how did you get those two numbers and what exactly they represent (note that 99% of people reading this question have no idea what is modbus). Your premise "I have two ushort integer. Integers :-32768, 16992" is already wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for `unchecked` in the context (do not throw `IntegerOverlow` but use silently binary complement value):

```
void Main()
{
    // unchecked(...) <- do not throw exception
    GetSingle(16992, unchecked((ushort)-32768));
}
```

Or

```
void Main()
{
    unchecked 
    {
        GetSingle(16992, -32768);
    }
}
```

The outcome of `GetSingle` method is

```
56.125
```

Comment: Thank you! Unchecked method works for me. Need your help on how to write this unchecked in VB.Net? Appreciate your help, Thanks

Comment: @Lawrence1987: As far as I can see, in case of `VB.Net` there are no `checked` `unchecked` keywords; but you can switch overflow check off at the project level: Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Build -> Advanced (button) -> Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow

Comment: Hi Dmitry: I'm getting `unchecked` working on `linqpad c# program` but when i've implemented this logic in my c# application it doesn't work. Is there any other setting we have do set like you mentioned for VB.net?

Comment: @Lawrence1987: are you working with C# or VB.Net? What's your implementation which doesn't work?

Comment: @Lawrence1987: what is your code which doesn't work?

Comment: @Lawrence1987: you have *different* code in the question;  `GetFloatSingle(decimal highOrderValue...` is *another source* of OverflowException (`decimal` is wider *than* `ushort`)

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it!